# Convergence of a root series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider a decreasing function $\psi \colon \Bbb{R}^+ \to \Bbb{R}^+$ and fix an integer $n \geq 3$. For $0 \leq s \leq 1$ I'm trying to determine whether the convergence of the series
$$
\sum_{q=1}^\infty q^{n-s} \psi(q)^s
$$
implies the convergence of
$$
\sum_{q=1}^\infty q^{(2-n-s)/n} \psi(q)^{s/n}.
$$
I don't think that this should always be the case, so I'm currently looking for a counterexample.

---

All that I have so far is that both series converge when the ratio or limit test is conclusive for the convergence of $\sum \psi(q)$. In other words, we're looking for $\psi$ such that
$$
\lim_{q\to\infty} \psi(q)^{1/q} = 1.
$$
The only example I know of this is $\psi(q) = q^{-w}$ with $w > 1$, but then the first series converges iff $s > \frac{n+1}{w+1}$, while the second converges iff $s > \frac{2}{w+1}$, so the implication is true.